# How to use Window manager rules to hide application window in ubuntu with gnome environment

Tags: 20.04, gnome

I Have followed the link : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=268826, which states we can either use xdotool to hide the application window or use window rules.

I want to use the window manager rules to hide the application window but I m not able to find any resources on how to do it.
I am using ubuntu 20.04 which has gnome environment.

Any help on how to do it or any appropriate resource would help.

Comment: When running on Xorg, the metod you linked to will work. When on Wayland, the system depends on the window manager used. For Gnome, there are Gnome Shell extensions that expose dbus calls to manipulate windows from the command line.

Comment: Can u provide some details/resources on the Gnome shell extension, to manipulate/hide the application window from the command line?

Comment: Start with the extension "Window calls"